# Simple Extension to Run on every page on Frontend

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I need to create a simple functionality on Magento 2 to check if user is logged in or not on the front-end.

I want to run it on every front-end page, and set some certain session variables for logged in and non-logged in users.

So far I have created the module's required directories, created config and activated the module.

What I need to know is that should I use events/observer or helpers/controllers for the purpose or any other simpler way?

P.S. I do not need anything to display on the front-end, just some operation on server side.

Thanks

Comment: You need to display something on frontend or execute some javascript or do some operation on fly?

Comment: @KeyurShah thanks for reply, No, doesn't need to display anything on the front-end, just an operation on server end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`controller_action_predispatch`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Action/Action.php#L96) event to execute some code on every page. But make sure that you put your `events.xml` in frontend directory as you want to execute some code only on the frontend.

For example,

`app\code\YOUR_VEDNOR\YOUR_MODULE\etc\frontend\events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
        <observer name="log_some_custom_every_page" instance="YOUR_VENDOR\YOUR_MODULE\Observer\LogCustomDataObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Now you can create your observer file

`YOUR_VENDOR\YOUR_MODULE\Observer\LogCustomDataObserver`

```
<?php 

namespace YOUR_VENDOR\YOUR_MODULE\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class LogCustomDataObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
   {
       // perform your magic here
   }

}
```

Comment: It has worked flawlessly, Thank you so much.